# Trying to use php to make a simple image "gallery" in a webpage

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a basic gallery of sorts to put on a web page. This is my code so far:

```
<?
if($_REQUEST['cho'] == 'next')
{
  $img = $img + 1;
}
else
if($_REQUEST['cho'] == "previous")
{
  $img = $img - 1;
}
else
if(!$_REQUEST['cho'] == 'next')
{
  if(!$_REQUEST['cho'] == "previous")
  {
    $img = 1;
  }
}
?>

<center>
<table border =1>
<tr>
<td>
<form action="image.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="cho" value="previous">
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="image.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="cho" value="next">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<BR>
<table border =1>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="<? echo($img . ".jpg"); ?>">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is all saved in a file called `image.php`.

I can view the first image (named 1.jpg, all images are named like this.) and pushing the next button displays the second. But from then on pushing the `previous` button tries to load `-1.jpg` and `next` just loads the current image.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php sessions, or save it and pass it in a query string (?img=3 instead of ?cho=next, and auto compute the next and previous link)

```
<?php
$totalImages = 5;

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['currentImage'])) {
  $_SESSION['currentImage'] = 1;
}

if($_REQUEST['cho'] == 'next')
{
   if($_SESSION['currentImage'] === $totalImages) {
       $_SESSION['currentImage'] = 1;
   } else {
       $_SESSION['currentImage']++;
   }

}
elseif($_REQUEST['cho'] == "previous")
{
   if($_SESSION['currentImage'] === 1) {
       $_SESSION['currentImage'] = $totalImages;
   } else {
       $_SESSION['currentImage']--;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: I used a Query String. Thanks. Works now

Comment: @theThird, so you can mark one of the two answers with the correct tick, regards

Comment: Done, Sorry. Still new to this.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the scope of the variable $img. You currently have it being declared in each if statement. You should declare the variable before any looping so the value is persistent.

Take a look here:

```
<?

 $img = 1;

if($_REQUEST['cho'] == 'next')
{
  $img = $img + 1;
}
else
 if($_REQUEST['cho'] == "previous")
 {
   $img = $img - 1;
 }
else
 if(!$_REQUEST['cho'] == 'next')
{
  if(!$_REQUEST['cho'] == "previous")
  {
    $img = 1;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: in this case, $img will be either 0,1 or 2, those are limited options

Comment: Tried this, $img still wont go above 2, and now is being set to 0 rather than -1 when the previous button is pressed.